# Ошибка not writable при попытке перезаписать json строку из Питона

Tags: python, json

[image]

открываю .json файл из .py файла и пытаюсь одну из его строк перезаписать на локальную переменную. Вижу ошибку not writtable. Как исправить и в чем проблема?

Comment: with open('data.json', 'w') as fh:  
Вам надо указать, что вы открываете файл для написания, сделать это можно с помощью аргумента 'w'

Comment: @Karlson21 при использовании 'w' будет ошибка "not readable" и удалится старое содержимое, это немножко не то, чего хотел спрашивающий

Comment: @artaxerx , спасибо, но теперь в json-файле какой-то бред появляется - {"password": "pw"}"
}
Тут вообще не понимаю, в чем проблема может быть..

Comment: Исправил! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы открыли файл только для чтения, поэтому и нельзя его перезаписывать, при открытии нужно ещё задать параметр `mode` (см. http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio):

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as fh: #'r+' открывает файл на чтение и изменение
    data = json.load(fh)
    data["password"] = cpw
    fh.seek(0) # возвращаемся в начало файла, иначе новый JSON-объект допишется после прочитанного
    json.dump(data, fh)
```